# How to have a log scale plot so that the smallest value on the vertical axis is a power of 10

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following logarithmic plot shown below:

[image]

I want to change this plot so that the "`x` axis" is such that the vertical value lies at the smallest possible power of 10.  What I mean by this is that I would like to make sure that the horizontal axis seen at the bottom of the plot is perhaps `y = 10e-2`  such that the rightmost group of bars in the above plot can be above the "`x` axis". I tried 'xaxislocation' but it doesn't work.  In hindsight, I suppose the `y=10e0` line is not the `x` axis anyway.

```
% plot group_err
data_names = cell(1,8);
data_names{1}='1'; data_names{2}='2';
data_names{3}='3'; data_names{4}='4';
data_names{5}='5'; data_names{6}='6';
data_names{7}='7'; data_names{8}='8';

h = bar(group_err);
grid on;
set(gca,'xticklabel',data_names,'YScale','log','FontSize',14);
ylabel('Error rate (%))','FontSize',14);
xlabel('Dataset','FontSize',14);
title('Error rate of sequential algorithms','FontSize',14);
ylim([0.01 100]);
```

group_err:

```
79.0407673860911    80.6235000000000    80.3837000000000
28.2600000000000    24.3600000000000    25.0200000000000
2.18055555555556    1.44290190000000    1.92145600000000
34.1692954784437    14.9053400000000    17.9127200000000
0.0551724137931035  0.0298850500000000  0.0459770500000000
33.2005921539600    22.4352400000000    25.6802200000000
0.0979391960824322  0.0685568400000000  0.155070440000000
```

Comment: A log plot can not have a 0, because `log(0)`? You could cheat it by changing the axis labels/ticks, but it would be fake, as the 0 in this plot is infinitely to the bottom

Comment: @AnderBiguri His intent is quite clear from the picture IMO. It is not uncommon to refer to 10^0 and 10^1 as 0 and 1.

Comment: @Bernhard not uncommon where? Never ever seen it. Also, to be consistent then 10^2 needs to be 2, and 10^3 is 3 , and.... Oh wait, that is not a logarithmic plot

Comment: @AnderBiguri In every field where dB is used as a unit. But OK, maybe the OP should be clear, because I agree that it is confusing.

Comment: @Bernhard oh, yes actually, you may be rigth. but, Isn't decibels logaritmic per se? you dont plot a log plot with dbs, you plot a linear plot with dbs as units, rigth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want in to change the 'BaseValue' property of your bar plot, in your case would be:

```
set(h,'BaseValue',0.01)
```

You will get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Now that we've seen your edit, that's very straight forward.  Simply find whatever `y` value is the smallest and you need to round this down so that the resulting value is a power of 10 **and** is smaller than the smallest `y` value you're looking at.

To do this, you want to the **floor** of the following relationship where given your minimum value `ymin`, it satisfies this relationship:

```
10^floor(x) = ymin
```

Re-arranging this equation by taking the `log` of both sides, we get:

```
x = log(ymin) /  log(10)
```

... and we now take the `floor` of `x` to get what you need.  Take special note that you need to take the `floor` as it rounds down to minus infinity.  Don't use `fix` as this rounds towards 0 so for negative values, this will **add** 1 to negative values and not what you want.  Specifically, this will ensure that you find the smallest power `x` that respects negative powers when the above relationship is less than 1.

The value of `x` serves as the smallest **power** of 10 that satisfies what you need.  You will the need to take `10^x` to complete the task. This is the smallest power of 10 that will serve as the horizontal axis of your plot.  You then use [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) to limit the vertical axis so that you see what the smallest and largest values you have.  Because you are using a semi-logarithmic plot, to do what you need you must specify these values as powers of 10.  This is the whole reason why we need to determine the smallest power of 10 to serve as the minimum limit or the `x` axis of your data.

Therefore, assuming you have your plot already open, simply do the following:

```
x = floor(log(min(y)) / log(10));
ylim([10^x max(y)]);
```

`ylim` takes two values: The minimum value and maximum value of the `y` axis you would like to see.  I've made sure that the largest value to visualize is just the largest value in your data itself.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng, I already set the ylim to to a range where all my data lies, but the plot still is the same.

Comment: You sure? This works on some tests that I performed.  Please show us the exact code you used to reproduce your data so I can try it.

Comment: Say I know that all my y values lie in (10e-2, 10e2), I set ylim([0.01 100]). Did I get it right here?

Comment: Yup, that's right.  Calling `ylim` should have changed your `y`-axis immediately.

Comment: The data shown in your post does not match the data seen in your plot. `bar` does not actually reproduce the plot you have shown above.  `bar` already draws a bar from the bottom of the plot to where each `log10(y)` value occurs so my code in my answer would certainly have no effect.  How did you produce the data seen in your image?  If the image is not a representation of the data you are looking for, please update your post and perhaps update the problem description as we are possibly venturing into territory that is no longer pertaining to this exact problem.

Comment: Sorry I'd shown the wrong data. I've corrected it as well as the code.

Comment: You're still using `bar` which still draws vertical bars from the bottom of the plot to each `y` value in your data.  However, I can see (on my end) that the lowest `y` value is 0.01 and that corresponds to your "x" axis. I'm not sure what your problem is now.